# change html DOCTYPE in my website

Tags: javascript, html

In my website I start from a very simple template of free version that I found in the Internet.
And I start to build on it a whole website.

Now when I wanted to add an INPUT that called: "range" (like slider if you know what I mean),
the IE browser interpret that like textbox.
I checked and understand now that not all browsers support that the range input...

In addition I found that the template of the website have a DOCTYPE of old version of HTML...

It look like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

When I tryed to change it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

My start page does not look good becouse I wrote a code in it that represent flow chart with arrows
and the code of the arrows not works with these DOCTYPE's...

the code of arrows:

```
<script> 
            function draw_arrow(context, startX, startY, size) 
            { 
                var arrowX = startX - 0.75*size; 
                var arrowTopY = startY - 0.707*(0.25*size);  
                var arrowBottomY = startY + 0.707*(0.25*size); 
                context.moveTo(startY, startX);
                context.lineTo(startY-size, startY); 
                context.lineTo(arrowX, arrowTopY); 
                context.moveTo(startY-size, startY); 
                context.lineTo(arrowX, arrowBottomY); 
                context.stroke(); 
            } 
            window.onload = function(){ 
                var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
                var startX = 100;  
                var startY = 100;  
                var size   = 100; 
                context.lineWidth = 4; 
                draw_arrow(context, startX, startY, size); 
                var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas2"); 
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
                var startX = 100;  
                var startY = 100;  
                var size   = 100; 
                context.lineWidth = 4; 
                draw_arrow(context, startX, startY, size); 
            }; 
        </script>
```

What can I do with the DOCTYPE title so that the arrows's chart and the INPUT range will looks good
together ? 
or how can I change my website so that support high versions of HTML without
do damage to the website...?

thanks...

Comment: It is called you have to sit down and change your old code so it works.

Comment: A DOCTYPE tells the browser which settings the rendering engine should use, changing it changes how some things get rendered and some of these changes (usually margin/padding/borders) can mess up styles etc. You have to re-align it.

Comment: now I remove the code of arrows and copy input range in the start page and it steel look like textbox, I  change the DOCTYPE to <!DOCTYPE html>, is this the right definition of HTML5 DOCTYPE?